# What is the meaning of AFT in airworthiness directives?

Tags: terminology, airworthiness-directive

What is the meaning of AFT in airworthiness directives?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The average flight time (AFT) is defined as flight hours (FH) divided by flight cycles (FC) accumulated by an individual airplane since the airplane's first flight, specified in hours and hundredths of an hour.

Comment: The "special" needs to be done within 34,500 flight cycles or 172,600 flight hours? That's a _lot_ of time in the air, is it not?

Comment: it’d be about 20 years for a 6-cycle-a-day short haul aircraft. The test in question seems to be a fairly intensive test for cracks, so presumably it’s something that applies only to old aircraft that the owners want to keep flying.

Comment: exactly, A/C was manufactured in 2002